# Android (Java) ViewPager with Fragments after weakup mSwipeRefreshLayout send error

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

My app has
a main activity with ViewPager and three tabs with Fragments. Each Fragment  is a ListView with SwipeRefreshLayout. 
If my app goes in background - 3-5 hours, I think, it gets loaded from taskmanager, it reloaded and it is fork. But if I call fragment from main activity (i call another activity with filter) with code

```
@Override
public void onRefresh() {


    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
        // начинаем показывать прогресс
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // ждем 3 секунды и прячем прогресс
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                arrayVideo.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                offset = 0;
                isEnd = false;
                loadVideoList(limit, offset,
                        activity.settings.getString("videoFilterName", ""),
                        activity.settings.getInt("videoFilterSector", 0),
                        activity.settings.getInt("videoFilterNumber", 0),
                        activity.settings.getInt("videoFilterMain", 0));
                offset += limit;

                // говорим о том, что собираемся закончить
                //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.refresh_finished, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

it causes a  crash.

Questions:
1) how am I repeatedly getting this error ? What actions is needed? (onStop.....)
2) What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the crash logs

Comment: it happens not often one time a day then I turn on my phone, and never then I debug my app. Because I haven't logs for chat. But one time I see, that  mSwipeRefreshLayout  was null. But it is very strange... because fragment was recreating.

Comment: Thanks, sonnet, I catched it. After refresh links of  fragments in main activity == null. Maybe refresh of fragments not refresh links in main activity.  So, I rewrote my code and will talk about results

Comment: After my edits I saw that after recreate main activity  I cant call my fragments from pageAdapter. So Question - how right call fragments in TabsLayout?                                 I use Api 28 without android x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, this is truth call to Fragments from parent Activity:

```
VideoListFragment videoListFragment = (VideoListFragment) pagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, TAB_VIDEO);
```